# PHP generating pages, but not returning them to the user right away

Tags: php, apache

I'm currently testing the load capacity of a server setup I'm putting together.  The apache2 server has PHP 5.X installed on it, and it connects to a master database on a seperate machine, and then 1 of 2 slave servers to do read froms.

My test page takes .2 seconds to generate if I call it by itself.  I created a php script on a different server that creates 65 simultaneous calls to the test page.  The test page takes microtime benchmarks throughout the page to let me know how long each section is taking.  As expected - at least to me, if anyone has opinions or suggestions on this, feel free to comment-,  the SQL portion of the page takes a short amount of time for the first couple requests it receives and then degrades because the rest of the queries stack up and have to wait.  I thought that it may be a disk IO issue, but the same behavoir occured when testing on a solid state drive.

My issue is that about 30 or so of 65 pages are created, and loaded by my test script as I expected.  My benchmark said the page was created in 3 seconds for example, and my test script said it received the page in full in 3.1 seconds.  The differential wasn't much.  The problem is that for the other requests, my benchmark says the pages were loaded in 3 seconds, but the test script didn't receive the page in full until 6 seconds.  that's a full 3 seconds between the page being generated by the apache server and sent back to my test script that requested it.  To make sure it wasn't an issue with the test script, I tried loading the page in a local browser while it was running, and received the same delay confirmed via the timeline window in Chrome.

I have tried all sorts of configurations for Apache, but can't seem to find what is causing this delay.  My most recent attempt is below.  The machine is a quad core AMD 2.8Ghz with 2Ghz of Ram.  Any help with configuration, or other suggestions on what to do would be appreciated.  -- Sorry for the long question.

I should mention that I monitored the resources while the script while it was running, and the CPU hit a max of 9% load and always had at least 1 gig of ram free.

I'll also mention that the same type of thing occurs when all I'm querying is a static HTML page.  The first couple take .X seconds, and then it slowly ramps up to 3 seconds.

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 120
MaxClients            150
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 4
MaxKeepAliveRequests 150

Header always append x-frame-options sameorigin

    StartServers         50
    MinSpareServers      25
    MaxSpareServers      50
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0


User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
AccessFileName .httpdoverride

    Order allow,deny
DefaultType text/plain
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf
Include httpd.conf
Include ports.conf

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
Include conf.d/
Include sites-enabled/
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps



    SecRuleEngine On
    SecRequestBodyAccess On
    SecResponseBodyAccess Off
    SecUploadKeepFiles Off
    SecDebugLog /var/log/apache2/modsec_debug.log
    SecDebugLogLevel 0
    SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly
    SecAuditLogRelevantStatus ^5
    SecAuditLogParts ABIFHZ
    SecAuditLogType Serial
    SecAuditLog /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log
    SecRequestBodyLimit 131072000
    SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 131072
    SecResponseBodyLimit 524288000
        ServerTokens Full
        SecServerSignature "Microsoft-IIS/5.0"
```

UPDATE:
It seems alot of responses are are focusing on the fact that the SQL is the culprit.  So I'm stating here that the same behavoir happens on a static HTML Page.  The results of a benchmarking are listed below.

```
Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   5.453 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        899
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 899, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      290877 bytes
HTML transferred:       55877 bytes
Requests per second:    183.38 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       54.531 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       5.453 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          52.09 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   21 250.7      0    3005
Processing:    16   33  17.8     27     138
Waiting:       16   33  17.8     27     138
Total:         16   54 253.0     27    3078

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     27
  66%     36
  75%     42
  80%     46
  90%     58
  95%     71
  98%     90
  99%    130
 100%   3078 (longest request)
```

I'll also state that I determined through the use of PHP and microtime() that the lag is happening before the page is being generated.  I determined this through the difference in time between the page being generated and my test script receiving it.  The difference is consistent meaning the amount of time from the point the page is generated until the point my test page receives it was the same no matter how long the entire request took.

Thank you to all who have responded.  All are good points, I just can't say any of them have solved the issue.

Comment: Try higher StartServers and MinSpareServers.  In my experience, it can take a while for apache to start extra threads when hit with a sudden burst of traffic.  In the grander scheme of things, proxy through a fast reverse proxy (nginx) to respond to connections faster and free up apache threads faster.  Even better, cache pages with squid/varnish so you don't waste resources generating the exact same content hundreds of times.

Comment: Ah, just noticed the bit about the database.  1) Avoid writes if possible 2) Identify which queries are slowing down 3) cache to avoid database access entirely.  I'd do some benchmarking -- record query time for every query, and generate a list of all queries run, ordered from slowest to fastest during a request.

Comment: Good question, just belongs on a different site.

Comment: @AJ - Why doesn't it belong on this site?

Comment: @Frank:  1) The only writes I'm doing are to a memory based table.  2) It's actually the exact same query run 10 times on each page.  select * from table LIMIT 1000;  3)  I upped the cache on the database server, but it doesn't want to cache it for some reason.  On the apache front, 1) I tried through a reverse proxy and direct to the machine with the same results.  2)  I could cache the pages, but the production environment doesn't serve pages with the exact same content very often, so the testing wouldn't simulate actual usage.  I will post the results of the higher values in a minute.

Comment: Doubling the Start servers and MinSpareServers has no effect.  The worst of the offenders still takes 3 seconds to generate the page, and 9 total seconds to get back to the client.  That's 6 extra seconds I can't account for.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1000` is doing a full-table scan; why are you doing this? This is the issue, it's not cached as it's a full-table scan, and it will block all other threads until it returns the first 1000 results. Is this a real-world example, or are you trying to make the test hard to optimize?

Comment: The SQL is not the issue I assure you.  I timed the SQL and the return seperately.   I also tried it with a static HTML page that had no database or php work and got the same lag time result.  And yes, I was trying to create an intensive page to try to optimize.

Comment: Are you warming up the server first? e.g. run your test a couple times and then run it again 30-60 seconds later to make sure it not just a warm up issue. Also since this is also happening for static requests you should just test static requests until that is fixed and then go to your php/mysql benchmarks.

Comment: 3 things that are red flags to me. 1) you are running apache on Windows. Although this is certainly possible, it shouldn't be a production environment and as long as you are doing benchmarks they should be as close to production as possible. 2) you are using a custom script instead of something like httpperf or other command line tools that are built specifically for http benchmarks. They will give you better data that will help you debug. 3) are you running the test script on the same machine as the server? this will almost always give weird and unreliable results

Comment: I also tried loading static content 5 simultaneous requests at a time for 20,000 iterations.  The server should be "warmed" up by the time 100,000 requests have gone through it.  Even after that pages that should load in .2 seconds were taking up to 7 seconds.   1) I'm not running Apache on windows. It just says that.  2)  As I stated, If I load the test page in my own browser while the test script is running, I get the same lag.  Therefore I don't see how it could be the test scripts error.  3)  The machines are seperate.

Comment: Perhaps your using fastcgi and you dont have enough php worker processes?

Comment: I don't believe I am using fastcgi.  Would that have any effect on non PHP pages?

Comment: We may have traced this issue to a networking issue.  Something to consider if you're having a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are many other factors, but I'm really guessing that you're spawning 30-40 processes quickly using using 30M or so each and killing your machines limited memory, then continuing to spawn new ones and thashing to swap, slowing everything down.

With 2G of ram, MaxClients at 150 and MaxRequestsPerChild at 0 the server resources are probably getting swamped even if your DB isn't on the same physical server.

Basically, for web server performance you don't want to ever swap.  Run your tests and then immediately check memory on the web server with a:

```
free -m
```

This will give you memory usage in MB and swap usage.  You should ideally see swap either 0 or close to 0.  If not zilch or very low swap usage, the issue is simply memory running out and your server is thrashing therefore wasting CPU resulting in slow response time.

You need to get some numbers to be certain, but first do a 'top' and press Shift-M while top is running to sort by memory.  The next time you run your tests and find a ballpark number on how much %MEM is being reported for each httpd process.  It will vary, so it's best to use the higher ones as your guide for a worst case bound.  I've got a wordpress, a drupal, and a custome site on the same server that routinely allocates 20M per http process from start and eventually grow in time upwards--if unchecked past 100M each.

Pulling some numbers out of my butt for example, if I had 2G and linux, core services, and mysql were using 800M, I'd keep expectations for memory I'd want to assume available for Apache fun to be under 1G.  With this, if my apache processes were using on the high side an average of 20M, I could only have 50 MaxClients.  Thats a very non-conservative number, in real life I'd drop Max down to 40 or so to be safe.  Don't try to pinch memory... if you're serving up enough traffic to have 40 simultaneous connections, pony up the $100 to go to 4G before inching up the Max servers.  It's one of those, once you cross the line everything goes down the toilet, so stay safely under your memory limits!

Also, with php I like to keep the MaxRequestsPerChild to 100 or so... you're not CPU bound serving web pages, so don't worry about saving a few milliseconds spawning new child process.  Setting it to 0 means unlimited requests and they never be killed off unless the total clients exceed MaxSpareServers.  This is generally **A VERY BAD THING** with php using apache workers as they just keep growing on until badness occurs (like having to hard restart your server because  you can't log in cause apache used up all memory and ssh can't work without timing out).

Good Luck!

Comment: I didn't think it went into swap, I was monitoring usage. I have gotten 4 gigs of RAM now, so I will repeat the tests when I have time to see if the results differ.

Answer (score 1):

What is the *exact* number of pages that load before the drop off? You mentioned that you were creating 65 simultaneous requests from a single, external script. You don't have a mod like limitipconn enabled that would be limiting things after N connections from a single IP or something? Is it always exactly 30 (or whatever) connections and then delay?

Comment: It's always a random amount before it drops off.  If I scale back the simultaneous requests, sometimes it will go 1000 page loads before one takes 3 seconds.